# Display RGB color values in Android Studio

Tags: android

I try to display color values like in the image:
COLOR: 195r 30g 110b

when I click on button every time display a random color
I use this code for generate colors but doesn't display what I want

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

        textView.setText("COLOR: " + color);
```

[image]

and this what output displayed
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you post what is being displayed as the output?

Comment: I posted you can check now

Comment: you're showing the color's integer value.  You don't want to do that.  You need to concatenate a string.  You need to do this:  Step 1:  Store the three values you are randomly generated in three variables.  Step 2:  Create the color with them.  Step 3.  Build a string to show the values.  You are missing step 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Random#nextInt(int)**

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 and the specified value.

**Color#rgb(int, int, int)**

> Returns a color-int from red, green, blue components. The alpha component is implicity 255 (fully opaque). These component values should be [0..255], but there is no range check performed, so if they are out of range, the returned color is undefined.

***Color#rgb(256, 256, 256)*** - Returns an undefined color because the values are out of range [0..255].

So in your case, you'll need something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int red = rnd.nextInt(255);
int green = rnd.nextInt(255);
int blue = rnd.nextInt(255);
int color = Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
textView.setText("COLOR: " + red + "r " + green + "g " + blue + "b");
```

Or:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int color = Color.rgb(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255));
textView.setText("COLOR: " + ((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + "r " + ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + "g " + (color & 0xFF) + "b");
```